# Searchbar works correctly but doesn't show any results

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, is-empty

I've added a search bar to my project and it works quite well. You can search for object (of a table view) and the relations also work. But the search display doesn't show the result names.

For example: I have no object which begins with "x" >>> So no result (That's correct):

[image]

But one object starts with "b", but the name isn't displayed although I can click on it and it shows me the next view (Relation) correctly:

[image]

Maybe this is caused due to my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"CarCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {

    Car *search = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UILabel *carNameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    carNameLabel.text = search.name;
```

I don't know why this doesn't work and this seems to be very strange to me.
It would be great if someone can help me.

**Update: Full method**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"CarCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {

     Car *search = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UILabel *carNameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    carNameLabel.text = search.name;

} else {
    Car *car = [cars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImageView *carImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    carImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:car.thumbnail];

    UILabel *carNameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    carNameLabel.text = car.name;

    UILabel *carSpeedLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
    carSpeedLabel.text = car.carSpeed;

}

return cell;
```

}

Comment: Can u log the search.name for the first record and the number of rows for search 'b' and kindly shift the code for self.searchdisplaycontroller first and place the other code beneath in proper if else form.

Comment: +1 for fixing images.

Comment: @yunas What do you exactly mean?

Comment: Can you put your whole code for the `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to fetch the `UILabel`s that you're setting by `tag` values, but you're using a stock `UITableViewCell`.  Try the following:

```
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    Car *search = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = search.name;
} else {
    Car *car = [cars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:car.thumbnail];

    cell.textLabel.text = car.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = car.carSpeed;
}
```

If you don't want to use the standard `UIView`s that are built into a normal `UITableViewCell`, you'll have to create and add your custom views (and set their `tag` property) in the block where you create new cells.

Answer (score 0):

If the updated code is the entire `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method then you didn't add the `carImageView`, `carNameLabel`, and `carSpeedLabel` views to your cell.

You need to add and configure those subviews, including with the appropriate tags, when you initialize a new cell. You should add the views to `cell.contentView` and then use `[cell.contentView viewWithTag:X]` to retrieve them.